# Disable trackpad and trackpoint via command line

Tags: command-line, mouse

For my rotation script, I'd like to disable the trackpoint when I have the screen rotated. It is pretty annoying if the screen is folded onto the keyboard and then moves the mouse with the trackpoint.

Is there some way to disable (and enable) the trackpoint via the command line and keeping the touch and pen input active?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [SynapticsTouchpad - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad):

Determine the device id:

```
xinput list
```

Disable it (e.g. here the device id is 15)

```
xinput set-prop 15 "Device Enabled" 0
```

Or see:

- [[SOLVED] Temporarily disable TrackPoint? - Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9407186)
- [How to disable the touchpad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-touchpad)

Comment: Yeah, I got it perfect now :-)

Comment: How to make this setting permanent?