# Script or Command Line for enabling/disabling touch pad

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, command-line

Is it possible for someone to help me out with my problem ?

I would like to know whether it is possible to enable/disable touch pad using command line or via scripting ?

Comment: Nvm..this post solved my problem :)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/148259/disable-trackpad-and-trackpoint-via-command-line?rq=1