# cursor jumps when moving (and some other times)

Tags: mouse, 12.10, cursor, flicker

i updated to 12.10 beta 1 when it was released (coming from 12.04 fresh install, i skipped the alpha releases of 12.10)

since then i've done all the usual updates but ive had an issue with my cursor jumping. it does not jump when typing, i've done a lot of searching and cant find an answer, it tends to happen most when i move the cursor
the jump is maybe 15-20 pixels down and to the right

it seems like a display issue because if i hover over a link or the x to close a window the cursor will settle in it's down/right position, but the whatever im hovering over will still act as if that's where the mouse is, and clicking still works on the item. so the mouse is actually in its original location, but it's displaying offset and flickering back and forth from its down/right position and its correct position

this makes use very difficult because the mouse is never displayed where it actually is and i have to estimate my clicks

any ideas?

Clarity: the issue I have is on a full install, not virtual box.

Comment: is this a virtualbox install or a laptop install?  This sounds like a bug.

Comment: Primary install on my netbook. Happens with mouse plugged in and using built in track pad.

Comment: My upgrade to 12.10 didn't go well... I too have the same issue (I think) Ubuntu 12.10 on Virtual Box 4.2.2 A video of my problem can be seen here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7Pih8pQ37k Does your installation do something similar with what you see on the video? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem too as of today. Ubuntu 12.10 AMD64, ATI HD 4600, Unity desktop.
The mouse cursor is making sudden jumps, sometimes it clicks on buttons (or links) without me clicking and often scrolls the screen upwards or downwards without me doing anything.
It happens in any application I tested so far, that is the desktop itself, Firefox and Chromium. To make sure I have exchanged the mouse with the result that new mouse shows the exact same behavior.

Comment: +0, since the question is in all-lowercase.

Comment: Sorry about the lower case question. Anyway this is a couple years old now and seems to have been resolved in the distribution, or it was a one-off fluke issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full format and clean install seems to have cleared it up.

Comment: That is how we usually do it in Soviet Russia :) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmPG5WfO14A

Answer (score 6):

I use VirtualBox (4.2.4r81684) on a Windows 7 host, had ubuntu desktop 12.04 guest, upgraded to 12.10 recently, and experienced this mouse jumping you describe, even after updating guest additions.

[This](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1041063) helped me out:

Long story short: this bug will be fixed eventually. You can either run these commands on EVERY boot (can put into a script in your .bash_profile, or something similar):

```
xinput set-prop "VirtualBox mouse integration" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0.5 0 0 0 0.5 0 0 0 1.0
xinput set-prop "VirtualBox mouse integration" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1.0 0 0 0 1.0 0 0 0 1.0
```

OR you can install the bug fix:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:a7x/bug1041063
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I installed the fix, and am happy to say that the problem has been resolved for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on a `VirtualBox`, and your issue is with Ubuntu 12.10. 
You can avoid this issue by pressing the right hand <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> also called `host-i`.
This enables and disables mouse integration, because the issue is caused by a mouse integration problem between your host machine and `VirtualBox`.

If you are not using a `VirtualBox` virtual machine to run Ubuntu 12.10, but you are using a laptop with a touch pad, [here](http://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-fix-cursor-jumping-in-ubuntu/) is a website to look at for possible fixes:

You can also disable or enable a touch pad, and many other devices, by following the instructions found in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-touchpad) link.

Other than this, I have not found any other resolutions for this issue.

Comment: Interestingly, with my installtion the problem only occured with the VirtualBox window located on the _second_ screen (which is the one I usually prefer on the system). Moving the window to the first screen fixed the problem (at least as a workaround).

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem on a Virtualbox install with both touchpad and USB mouse -- my mouse tends to move to position 0 for x and/or y intermittently.  I have gnome installed and it was causing the desktop to show the window previews when I'm moving my mouse in the middle of the screen so I disabled the auto-preview in corner feature because it was becoming unbearable.