# How do I fix the mouse after pairing with Bluetooth?

Tags: 12.04, mouse, bluetooth

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on it.

I paired a Bluetooth mouse with it, which caused the touch pad on the laptop to stop working.

After the computer was suspended over night, I tried to use the mouse when it said:

```
Mouse is trying to access your computer, grant access?
```

But I can't click the buttons as now neither the touch pad nor the mouse works.

I can't <kbd>alt</kbd>+ <kbd>tab</kbd> to the window as it opens under the other windows and does not show in the list.

I tried enabling mouse control via the keyboard using `Universal Access` but I don't have a keypad on my laptop.

Comment: What is it when you say you don't have a "keypad"?

Comment: The image you posted doesn't seem to clarify much, can you be a little more verbose or post a better picture?

Comment: @Jobin as in a laptop doesn't have the `0-9 /*-+. enter, num lock` keys on the right of the keyboard, like a normal desktop keyboard. The "Universal Access" setting binds these to move the mouse. But because I don't have them I still cannot move the mouse.

Comment: Did you get your problem solved, Petah?

Comment: @Private yes, but I did not try your solution. Out of luck, some how the window got focus (no idea how it happened), and then I used the keyboard to click the button. I will let the bounty run a little longer, then you will get the points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question. Here is a workaround.

1. Open a terminal. Use the windows key to open the HUB and type `terminal` and use the arrows keys to open a terminal.
2. Type the command `xinput` in the terminal. That will give you a list of the input keyboard and pointer inputs on your computer. It will look something like the table below.
3. Find the entry that says `touchpad` and enable it as follows. You can enable it by typing `xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 1` (`set-prop` means set the property and the `1` means `put it on`). To switch it off, for instance, you would use `xinput set-prop 16 "Device Enabled" 0`.
4. Hit the button you want and enjoy control over your computer. Find out whether the error occurs again. If so, google, ask a question here or file a bug (in that order).

This is the table you will see in step 2:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_1.3M             id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

This is a comparable question: [How to disable the touchpad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-touchpad)

Comment: It's good manual, but could you explain please, what is 16 in this command `xinput set-prop 16 "Device Enabled" 1`? Why exactly 16? Touchpad id is _12_. That's why I' asking

Comment: Good question, the 16 in this example should 12. It is 16 on my system and could be something else on your system.