# Disable Laptop Touchpad

Tags: touchpad, xinput

I'm using a Lenovo x230 laptop which features a touchpad and a trackpoint.  I love the trackpoint and dislike the touchpad -- I continuously hit it with my thumb.

I would like to disable the touchpad, but leave everything else working. I've tried using xinput by putting the following in my .xinitrc:

```
$ xinput --disable 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
```

This works, however, after a few minutes, the touchpad becomes enabled again. I'm not sure why this is happening.  Is this the best way to persistently disable the touchpad?

Comment: You should be able to use the answer provided there: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-touchpad#67724  
Best,

Comment: That is where I got this command from.  However, the same thing happens: the touchpad gets re-enabled after a few minutes.

Comment: Are you on 12.04 or 12.10?

Comment: This is good to know, however I feel there needs to be a "disable-touchpad" setting under "mouse" to Automatically disable touchpad when a mouse is plugged in. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following methods will ensure your changes persist as long as you use `gnome`:

1. Install and run `dconf-editor` (if you're on 12.10, `dconf-editor` might be pre-installed):

   `$ sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

   `$ dconf-editor`
2. Go to the following settings directory:

   `org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals`
3. Under `touchpad`, uncheck the `touchpad-enabled` checkbox.

If you prefer not to meddle with `dconf-editor`'s GUI, run the following command instead:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled false
```

Comment: Yes this  will also work on 12.10

Comment: Perfect! I did not know that. I also edited my answer in case readers do not want to install `dconf-editor`.

Comment: It’s pre-installed on 12.10 and later.

Comment: *sigh* editing again

Comment: Works great using dconf. However, my system doesn't seem to have a "gsettings" command.