# Re-enabling touchpad after disabling it with xinput?

Tags: 13.04, touchpad, toshiba-satellite, xinput

The only other [similar topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272863/touchpad-disabled-for-ubuntu-12-04-how-to-reenable) was asked in march 27 and was left unanswered.

Back when I first started with Ubuntu, around October, I was attempting to disable my touchpad because FN-F9 (on my toshiba laptop) does not work. In my annoyance I used [this help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-touchpad) and ran this command:

```
xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 0
```

I recently had the desire to re-enable my touchpad, and was attempting to do so, but, to my avail, I could not.

My settings do not list a touchpad

I ran

```
gpointing-device-settings
```

and this only lists my wireless mouse.

Toggling with

```
synclient touchpadoff=1
synclient touchpadoff=0
```

has no effect.

```
xinput
```

Does not list a touch pad, only a toshiba input device.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer            id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:1025   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard           id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                          id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                             id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                          id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Camera                            id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Toshiba input device                  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Touchpad indicator does not allow me to re-enable the touchpad.

So I booted into windows and re-enabled it. However, this method will not work for someone without a windows partition like I have and so we come back to my original question, how do I re-enable my touchpad?

Comment: To disable/enable the touchpad I use `synclient touchpadoff=1` and `synclient touchpadoff=0`, but I suppose it could not work on all touchpads.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I suppose I should have remembered that. But I tried that, and tried it again, and it has no effect.

Comment: I think you should use this: `http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/touchpad-indicator-now-automatically.html` for disabling touchpad

Comment: Can you enable it in BIOS? (please don't include "Solved" in your title...