# Is it possible to turn trackpad on/off manually?

Tags: trackpad

I would like to configure my Ubuntu such that I can use command line to say when the trackpad should register mouse moves and clicks and when not. Is that possible to do? And can I do it such that my USB-mouse would work all the time?

I tried to follow answer given in [How to disable the touchpad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-touchpad) but there were no trackpad in the list:

```
jaakko@jaakko-VPCEB1S1E:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Mouse                                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sony Vaio Keys                            id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB 2.0 Camera                            id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
jaakko@jaakko-VPCEB1S1E:~$
```

Comment: Check out this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-touchpad Basically use xinput in a script of your own which you use to toggle your trackpad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your touchpad just has an abstract name.

Try this command:

```
xinput disable 13
```

which disables the "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" device, then check if the touchpad works.

If it doesn't work, you can try disabling each of the pointers in turn (remember to enable the last one before disabling the next one!)

Note: You can re-enable a device with this command, replacing `$ID` wit the ID of the device:

```
xinput enable $ID
```

Comment: `xinput disable 14` was the correct number.