# How to disable the built in mouse pad in a laptop?

Tags: laptop

My touch pad is not functioning well , it make wrong moves even if i connect a usb mouse

is there a tip to disable it and just use the usb mouse ?

Comment: @vasa1 read the question well please , that question is different issue

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-the-touchpad

Comment: The solution as with so many other complex problems, is duct tape.