# How to quickly enable/disable touchpad in Xubuntu 14.04 without installing other applications?

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad

In Xubuntu 14.04. accessing the settings to disable and enable the touchpad are a bit hidden - in Settings-Mouse and Touchpad, and once there, there are a few other clicks needed.

[image]

I have tried by installing the panel application `touchpad-indicator` - but that seemed buggy in Xfce maybe due to conflicts with the Xfce settings...

Is there a quick and safe method to enable/disable touchpad?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That can be easily done with these two commands (inspired by a different [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/811822/47206)):

Disable:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=1
```

Enable:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

---

My initial answer was to use

```
xinput set-prop 15 "Device Enabled" 0
```

and

```
xinput set-prop 15 "Device Enabled" 1
```

where **the id number may be other than 15**: it can be be found by running

```
xinput list
```

I found about these commands in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/67724/47206) answer under [a question on how to disable the touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/q/65951/47206).

---

The commands can be added into launchers.

I prefer creating `.desktop` files (in `usr/share/applications` or in `.local/share/applications`) for the two commands to be run easily with a launcher like Whisker Menu, Synapse, etc

---

Also:

- by adding them into a single launcher,
- setting advanced properties like in the image below

[image]

(namely 'show last used item' and 'inside button'),

- and adding two specific icons,

***the launcher will always display the current status of the touchpad***.

[image]

---

Also it is never a bad idea to **assign shortcuts** (Settings Manager - Keyboard - Application Shortcuts) to the two commands.

Comment: Funny, the commands (at least with synclient) don't work on my Dell XPS 15 9570. :D

Answer (score 13):

You also can use *synclient*, [like in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443299/fn-key-for-touchpad-xubuntu).

To turn off touchpad:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=1
```

To turn on:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

I think this is more convenient way. You don't need to know device id.

So my solution is to create bash script *~/toggle-touchpad.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash
if synclient | grep --quiet 'TouchpadOff             = 0'; then
  synclient TouchpadOff=1
  notify-send Touchpad Disabled
else
  synclient TouchpadOff=0
  notify-send Touchpad Enabled
fi
```

Modify file permission:

```
sudo chmod +x ./toggle-touchpad.sh
```

Next goto Settings-Keyboard-Application Shortcuts and add new shortcut. Enter path to the script (/home/your_username/toggle-touchpad.sh - for example). Specify shortcut (Fn+F9 in my case).

Done. Now you can toggle touchpad and you will get notification.

Comment: Note to others, the spaces in the if statement are all necessary for this script to run correctly. Also, I think it should be `sudo chmod +x ~/toggle-touchpad.sh`

Comment: Also, if you like clean files/file structure you could always name the script ".toggle-touchpad.sh" (with a dot "." out front) so that it is a hidden file but will still run just fine.

Comment: This answer is better as `synclient TouchpadOff` etc doesn't need the `xinput list` *variable* (which *varies* from system to system); but I find the launchers more Xfce-friendly; so I'll integrate this into my answer

Comment: Unfortunately under kubuntu 18.04LTS it doesn't work. It changes the status number from 2 (the default) to 0 and 1... but do not disable the touchpad. Using `xinput --disable 12` where 12 is the number of the device it works. Nice use of notify send (+1).

Comment: @Hastur - the `synclient` method stopped working in recent systems, `xinput` method works.

Comment: @cipricus Yep, I was trying to say so... (_"but does not disable the touchpad"_). I use `xinput` myself (in my script)... and you seem to confirm that it works for you too... :-)

Answer (score 10):

The non-launcher version:

```
#!/bin/bash

# toggle state of synaptics touchpad

tpid=`xinput list | grep SynPS | sed 's/.*id\=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'`

declare -i status
status=`xinput list-props ${tpid} | grep Device\ Enabled | sed -e 's/.*\:[ \t]\+//g'`

if [ 0 -eq ${status} ] ; then
    xinput enable ${tpid}
else
    xinput disable ${tpid}
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

I have used @cipricus and @Demeter answers, but without using *synclient*, i thought that would be good to share:

```
#!/bin/sh

TOGGLE=$HOME/.toggle
TOUCHPAD_ID=$(xinput list | grep "Touchpad" | grep -Eow '[0-9]{2}')

if [ ! -e $TOGGLE ]; then
   touch $TOGGLE
   xinput set-prop $TOUCHPAD_ID "Device Enabled" 0
else
   rm $TOGGLE
   xinput set-prop $TOUCHPAD_ID "Device Enabled" 1
fi
```

Comment: `xinput disable ID` and `xinput enable ID`  also work. Notifications with icons can be added too: https://askubuntu.com/a/1318615/925128