# Installation of touchfreeze and gpointing-device-settings fails

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, input-devices

I use Ubuntu 16.04 on a HP Envy laptop.
My cursor is randomly jumping like described in https://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-fix-cursor-jumping-in-ubuntu/.

I'd like to use method 3, but I only get the following:

```
sudo apt-get install touchfreeze
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package touchfreeze is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'touchfreeze' has no installation candidate
```

I found another solution at [Touchpad issue: jumping cursor while typing (Ubuntu 14.04), syndaemon don't help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462135/touchpad-issue-jumping-cursor-while-typing-ubuntu-14-04-syndaemon-dont-help) and tried

```
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

but also having the same output above and can't install it either.

Is there a way to install either `touchfreeze` or `gpointing-device-settings` on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-the-touchpad, https://askubuntu.com/questions/773595/how-can-i-disable-touchpad-while-typing-on-ubuntu-16-04-syndaemon-isnt-working and https://askubuntu.com/questions/537002/how-to-quickly-enable-disable-touchpad-in-xubuntu-14-04-without-installing-other

Answer (score 0):

You can use `syndaemon` to automatically disable your touchpad while typing, e.g. do

```
syndaemon -i 2 -d
```

to disable (`-i`) it for `2` seconds. Read [`man syndaemon`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/syndaemon.1.html) for more. If this solution works for you, add the command to your Startup Applications as described here: [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

---

`touchfreeze` isn't in the 16.04 repositories, but you can download the `.tar.gz` package from [linux.softpedia.com](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/TouchFreeze-28533.shtml) and install it as explained here: [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

---

`gpointing-device-settings` isn't in the 16.04 repositories as well and doesn't seem safe to use any more, see here for more: [Is gpointing-device-settings in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783229/is-gpointing-device-settings-in-ubuntu-16-04/783234)