# Touchpad issue after ubuntu 18.04 upgrade

Tags: touchpad, 18.04, elantech

Few days earlier, I have updated my Ubuntu form 17.10 to 18.04.
Everything is running perfect, except touchpad.

Touchpad is not getting disabled while typing even if I have enabled this option in the settings. <kbd>Fn</kbd> key shortcut to disable the touchpad is also not working.

Every time, either I have to use `synclient TouchpadOff=1` command to disable the touchpad or need to change the touchpad option in settings.

Currently I am using [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/811822/146791) method as a workaround. Can anyone suggest any better approach so the it gets disabled automatically while typing.

I am using Asus R558U and here is the otput of `xinput` command.

```
guru@guru-notebook:~$ xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                             id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam: USB2.0 V           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
guru@guru-notebook:~$
```

Comment: Please check, when booted from an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS boot drive 'Try Ubuntu', if the touchpad works like it should. This way you can see, if the problem is 'an 18.04 LTS problem' or if it is caused by the upgrade process  (for example some old configuration, that no longer works).

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033033/elantech-touchpad-does-not-work-i2c-hid

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. XIAOMI AIR 13.

Before ubuntu 18, my touchpad only had his left button click working plus two finger touchpad and the right button was disabled. After 18 update, touchpad is working and also both buttons. But, the two fingers scroll stopped working. I'm struggling to get the two fingers scroll working again.

try this: remove readd the touchpad.

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```