# Toupad isn't usable on 21.10

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, 21.10

Hi i am using a "HTIX5288:00 0911:5288 Touchpad" an the hardware right click is just working like  a left click. When i am clicking on something, i also couldn't use the Mouse because it wouldn't move anymore. Can you help me maybe? This Problem is just present, since i updated to Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: It's quite hard to follow exactly what the problem is, but a quick thing to check - if you can navigate there - is in settings, under Mouse and Touchpad, there's an option to change the primary button of the device (ie switch the normal right and left button functions). I'm not sure that'll help but worth checking.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, there is nothing in the mouse or touchpad settings that allows me to adjust the click settings. Do you know of a way to expand the settings?

The other problem is that when I want to move a window, the mouse pointer no longer moves after the left click.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much this will help but there's too much detail in what I'm writing to put in a comment.

If the problem is your mouse left button behaves like a right button and you can't move the mouse when you click in order to change that, here are some keyboard tips that might help - I've just played around to see if I can change settings without using the left mouse button:

Right-click (ie left in your case) in the settings area and it opens up the menu then arrow keys let you move up / down through the options, enter to select - you should hopefully be able to open setting with this.

If you then can't navigate to the mouse / touchpad options because the cursor won't move, using arrow keys and tab (to go down / right) / shift-tab (to go up / left) you can navigate to the search icon at the top left (when it's highlighted with an orange box, hit enter to open the search bar). If you then type Mouse and hit enter, it will open up the relevant menu. You can tab to get in to the right hand side of the window and repeat tab until the primary button is highlighted as 'left' then hit space or enter to select it.

I'm not sure if this is the problem you're facing but it's worth looking there. It may well be that the problem is more of a driver issue if you've just upgraded, but this is a simple thing to check first. If it's more complicated, take a look at [How to troubleshoot a trackpad/touchpad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368212/how-to-troubleshoot-a-trackpad-touchpad) to see if it helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, you re awesome. In my Touchpad and Mouse settings their is no setting for the buttons. I just can use  the left handed  mode an get on both buttons just an rightcick. When i have the time, i will go thru you link which seams very promising.