# Terminal paging and scrolling

Tags: command-line, touchpad, scrolling

My terminal is very flaky. Even as I write this the webpage will scroll up and down almost at random. The same goes for my terminal. I will try to type, and the terminal will start paging and scrolling up and down seemingly without cause. 
As I write this, the page will scroll up and down as well. Also, sometimes when I am typing a white box will appear in the lower right corner of my screen with the letters and words of what I am typing. 
Can anyone tell me how to turn this behaviour off? Or at least what is causing it? There are times I can barely type. Is there a way to completely turn off terminal scrolling and paging completely? And why is this happening when I am on a webpage as well. I wonder if it has anything to do with my touchpad. 
Ubuntu 14 
HP 2000 Notebook

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If, like me, you are a lazy typist and your wrist rests on the touchpad, you will have problems.  If you have a separate mouse, you can turn off your touchpad for a while and see if this makes the problem go away

Comment: Thanks. That is it. I used the synclient TouchpadOff=1 command from this article http://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-the-touchpad

Comment: You should go ahead and type that into an answer - it will have to sit for a couple of days after that, but then you can accept the answer and call the question closed.

Answer (score 1):

The OP solved the problem and posted the solution in a comment. In reply to Charles Green's [suggestion to disable the touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515876/terminal-paging-and-scrolling#comment699492_515876), the OP wrote:

> Thanks. That is it. I used the synclient TouchpadOff=1 command from
>   this article
>   [askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-the-touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-the-touchpad)

–  [Guest123ABC](https://askubuntu.com/users/310757/guest123abc) [Aug 25 at 14:27](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515876/terminal-paging-and-scrolling#comment699508_515876)

<sub>This question *might* not be considered a *duplicate* of that, as disabling the touchpad is one of possibly multiple solutions to this problem.</sub>