# Is there a way to toggle the touch display in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, touchscreen

I have a laptop (Dell Inspiron) with a touch display. Is there a way to turn the touch functionality of this display off and on with the touch of a button or a key combination?

I am running Kubuntu 18.04

Comment: The same switch that worked in Windows is likely to work in Ubuntu.

Comment: @MichaelBay This does not really help. The laptop came preinstalled with Ubuntu. I don`t use Windows. I am searching for a software button since as far as I can tell there is no hardware button.

Comment: I use ` xinput --disable 'ELAN Touchscreen'` to disable mine, since I never use the touch capabilities.

Comment: @JohnAnderson stupid question, before I try: Will xinput --enable 'ELAN Touchscreen'  reenable it?

Comment: @JohnAnderson Ok, I tested. This works. Please add it as an answer.

Comment: @Bruni, that re-enables it on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xinput` utility provides a utility to configure and test X input devices. Do a `man xinput` for details. You can use `xinput list` to get a list of the devices on your system. `xinput --disable 'ELAN Touchscreen'` will disable an `ELAN Touchscreen` and `xinput --enable 'ELAN Touchscreen'` will re-enable the same device.

To actually create a toggle button you can adjust the answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677152/how-to-toggle-xinput-device-prop) question and put the resulting script in a .desktop file.

Comment: Since I never use the touch capabilities, I put the disable command as a `startup` program.