# After disabling touchpad in ubuntu16.04 I can't enable it again

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

After disabling touchpad, I can't find the switch button under the Mouse & touchpad.
The most suitable answer I found is knocte's answer under this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-the-touchpad).

The id for touchpad on my mechine is 13 rather than 7, so I replace "print $7" to "print $13". But when I do it, terminal shows this to me:"Usage: BLABLABLA", which notes me the wrong usage of the command. If I just copy the answer then it will show me:"can't find device slave".

the command I type is like this:

```
xinput set-prop `xinput --list | awk '/TouchPad.*pointer/ {print $13}' | sed 's/id=\(.*\)/\1/'` "Device Enabled" 1
```

How can I enable my touchpad again?

************second edit*****************

```
frank@frank-Inspiron-7447:~$ xinput set-prop 13 "Device Enabled" 1
frank@frank-Inspiron-7447:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳  USB OPTICAL MOUSE                        id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Wireless hotkeys                     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
frank@frank-Inspiron-7447:~$ xinput -list-props 13
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (139):   0
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (265): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (266):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (267):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (268):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (269):  1666, 5360, 1496, 4476
    Synaptics Finger (270): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (271):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (272):   242
    Synaptics Tap Durations (273):  180, 100, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (274):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (275):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (276):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (277):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (278): 110, 110
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (279): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (280):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (281): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.036252, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (282):    2
    Synaptics Locked Drags (283):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (284):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (285): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (286):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (287): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (288):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (289): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (290):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (291): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (292):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (293): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (294):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (295): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (296):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (297):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (298):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (299):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (300): 60, 41
    Synaptics Area (301):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (302):  3513, 0, 4094, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (303): 27, 27
    Device Product ID (259):    2, 7
    Device Node (260):  "/dev/input/event7"
frank@frank-Inspiron-7447:~$
```

Comment: Did you try all the options described in the link you provided? I see references to using `synclient TouchpadOff=0` and installing touchpad-indicator app

Comment: @GrannySez I tried most of them including the two you mentioned.

Comment: Maybe try simplifying your previous command to just `xinput set-prop 13 "Device Enabled" 1`. What output does this produce? Post your `xinput list` output and also `xinput -list-props 13` output.

Comment: @GrannySez Thanks for your reply. Here is the output thing. By the way, when I typed into Mouse & touchpad pane, that place where touchpad switch used to be was presented nothing, but blank.

Comment: This line seems to show the touchpad is still inactive "Device Enabled (139):   0". It should show 1 not 0. Try `xinput set-prop 13 139 1`.

Comment: @Still the same...

Comment: I'm out of ideas then ... Do you have a hardware switch on your machine to turn touchpad on/off?

Comment: @GrannySez Thanks for your advice. I'm gonna to drop this problem here and move on.

Comment: any success on your touchpad issue ? i have the same problem and i cannot find any working solution.

Comment: @Jakub Sorry, I didn't, after reinstall ubuntu, I switch it by 'xinput list' and 'xinput --enable' now. Check [this](https://github.com/DeathPoem/little_cave_local_files/blob/master/handy_script/my_switch_touchpad.sh)