# ThinkPad T410 volume buttons' indicators not working on Xubuntu

Tags: 16.04, sound, xubuntu, keyboard, thinkpad

I have a lenovo ThinkPad T410, running Xubuntu 16.04 up-to-date. there are 4 buttons for volume/sound control:
1. Mute speakers - It's working, but it has a red LED which should turn on when muted, but doesn't turn on.
2. Speakers volume down - working
3. Speakers volume up - working
4. Mute mic - indicator LED and the button both aren't working.

The problem is only in Xubuntu. I made a live USB of ubuntu 16.04 (not xubuntu), and from there, all those buttons are working.

P.S: The combination `Fn + F3` on ubuntu opens a window to display battery status, as it should, but does nothing in xubuntu.
And `Fn + F8` disables the trackpad on ubuntu, as it should, but its doing nothing in xubuntu.

How can I get these to work?

**EDIT:**
I have tried Kubuntu and budgie-remix too. The problem persists in Kubuntu  too, but budgie-remix works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution myself:
**For the mic mute button:**
 1. Open settings -> From "Hardware", select "Keyboard" -> "Application Shortcuts"
 2. Click on "Add"
 3. In Command, Type this: `amixer set Capture toggle`[image]
 4. Click "OK" -> Press the mute button.
 5. Done. Now when pressed, the mic will be mute-ed, and the indicator LED also turns on.

**For the trackpad disabling**:
 Repeat the same steps, except, instead of `amixer set Capture toggle` as the command, use this guide to get the command: https://askubuntu.com/a/67724/511354, and of course, press the trackpad-disable combination instead of min-mute key