# Auto-Disable Touchpad on LXDE

Tags: lubuntu, touchpad, lxde

Is there a way in LXDE to disable the touchpad when an external mouse is connected, and renabled when external mice are removed? I've tried the udev rules found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Disable_touchpad_while_typing), but it didn't work at all.

Comment: Maybe look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-the-touchpad