# How to configure Function keys on laptop Asus FX506HE-HN012 with Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: drivers, asus, 21.04, function-keys

On my laptop most function keys work, but <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> doesn't. It controls fan speed and mode, like performance or effectiveness or turbo. Also <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> which turns touchpad on and off.

I've installed the latest version of the kernel and updated Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

"fn" keys and combinations are implemented by your actual BIOS, and are not controlled by the operating system.

At least for disabling the touchpad, you can do that [using a script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-the-touchpad) or just **disable tap-to-click**.

For example, this is the script I use to disable tap-to-click with a shortcut key:

```
#!/bin/bash
STATUS=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click)
case $STATUS in
    true )
        gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click false
        gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method 'areas'
        # 2021-07-05 Change also click method: area when tap is off
        # notify-send "Tap-to-click Off"
    ;;
    false )
        gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true
        gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method 'fingers'
        # notify-send "Tap-to-click On"
    ;;
esac
```

- Save the contents in a text file, e.g. `~/bin/toggletouchpad`.
- Make that file executable: right-click, select the properties tab to set the executable bit.
- Create a shortcut key to toggle the setting, and as command, enter the full path name of the script: `/home/<yourlogin>/bin/toggletouchpad` (where `<yourlogin>` stands for your login name).

Remove the comment sign `#` if you like to see a notification when you change the status.