# Setting kernelmodule-options permanently? (fix touchpad scrolling error)

Tags: 11.10, kernel, touchpad

I was looking for a solution here and the answers were only to open the 'System Settings' and to change the settings there. This was no help for me but then I found this: [Touchpad not working on Dell XPS L501x](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65736/touchpad-not-working-on-dell-xps-l501x/66155#66155)
I followed the instructions and reloading the kernelmodule with that specific option helped me out (I run Oneiric on a Sony VPCEB1S1E). Now the question: how to set his Option permanently?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new file in /etc/modprobe.d, e.g. /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf and put this line into it:

```
options psmouse proto=imps
```

In case you don't know how to edit a file as root, you can use this command in a terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf
```