# How to make ubuntu support touchpad scrolling?

Tags: laptop, touchpad, mouse-scroll

I have a dell (inspiron n5110) laptop and manual book said that i can scroll using two fingers on the touch-pad and scroll up, down, left, and right it workd in windows but that didn't happen in Ubuntu 11.10.how to make this enable ???

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the model of your dell laptop? Also, please open a terminal, run `xinput --list`, and add the resulting text to your question. I suspect your touchpad may not be being detected as a touchpad, but rather as a plain mouse. The information I request may help us better direct you to a clear answer. Thanks!

Comment: Here it is http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/2653/touchpade.png

Comment: It seems that your touchpad is not been detected.Look at the answers of http://askubuntu.com/questions/65736/

Answer (score 11):

Did you try to open "System Settings"

[image]

and click on "Mouse and Touchpad", then select the "Touchpad" tab

[image]

and there select "Two Finger scrolling" and possibly "Enable horizontal schrolling"?

Comment: look at this (there is no touchpad tap) http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/2264/screenshotat20120103142.png

Answer (score 2):

if someone still looking for the solution so: 
 
open "System Settings" then click on "Mouse and Touchpad", then select the "Touchpad" tab 
 
and there **deselect** "Two Finger scrolling" 
 and if you want normal scrolling so deselect either the "natrual scrolling" 
 (enable it just if you want a scroll like apple).

Answer (score 0):

based on the xinput information you showed, it looks like your touchpad is not being recognized as such, but rather, as a simple PS/2 mouse with no scroll capabilities.

Dell has started using ALPS touchpads, which sometimes need some fiddling to make work, hopefully answers to this question will help you:

[How do I enable multi touch on a Dell inspiron n5110 with an ALPS touchpad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104431/how-do-i-enable-multi-touch-on-a-dell-inspiron-n5110-with-an-alps-touchpad)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone here is using Lubuntu, the steps are literally the same as mentioned above, but it's a little different.

**Click the Application Menu**, then go to **Preferences**>**LXQt Settings**>**Keyboard and Mouse**.When the window opens, select Mouse and Touchpad and then select your Touchpad from the **Device** dropdown.
Set the scrolling to Two Finger. Click **apply**.
Thanks for asking the question. Let me know if it helped!

Answer (score -1):

deselecting the "two finger scrolling" actually allows you to scroll. Seems backwards.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more?