# How do I enable multi touch on a Dell inspiron n5110 with an ALPS touchpad?

Tags: dell, multi-touch

How can I enable touch pad gestures(multi touch effects) of alps touch pad which comes with dell inspiron n5110 in ubuntu 11.10. These gestures worked fine with windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable two-finger scrolling on ALPS touchpad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24156/enable-two-finger-scrolling-on-alps-touchpad)

Comment: Here you can find a solution: http://askubuntu.com/a/199587/44254

Answer (score 3):

This blog post contains instructions for installing patched mouse drivers, which enable correct recognition of your touchpad:
http://nwoki.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/multitouch-fix-for-alps-touchpad/
Even this is a little outdated, as there have been several updates to the drivers since.

In short:
Download psmouse-alps-1.3: http://www.dahetral.com/public-download/psmouse-alps-1.3.tbz/view
Then (using sudo / root):

- Extract the folder `psmouse-alps-1.3` to `/usr/source`
- cd to `/usr/source`
- `dkms add psmouse-alps-1.3`
- `dkms autoinstall`
- `rmmod psmouse && modprobe psmouse`

Bam! Working multitouch! :-)

Possible duplicate: [Enable two-finger scrolling on ALPS touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24156/enable-two-finger-scrolling-on-alps-touchpad)

Comment: tried.... bt nt wrkng

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable your Dell Inspiron 15R Touchpad:

- download that `alps-dkms` package and install it in `/usr/src`.
- from a terminal, navigate to `/usr/src/psmouse-alps-0.10/src` and then `gedit alps.c`
- in `alps.c` scroll down and copy the `/* Dell Vostro 1400 */` line completely.  In that line you will have to replace first 3 matches, that is , replace 0x73 , 0x02 , 0x50 with 0x73 , 0x03 , 0x50 .
- Save the file and return to the terminal. In the terminal type `dkms add -m psmouse -v alps-0.10`
- After this, type `dkms build -m psmouse -v alps-0.10`
- after build is complete, install it with `dkms install -m psmouse -v alps-0.10`
- after it installs it successfully, type `rmmod psmouse && modprobe psmouse` This will reload your psmouse module.
- Next, type `xinput --list` to see whether it loaded successfully or not. If it shows `Alps/PS2 Alps GlidePoint` in the xinput , than congrats. And i bet it will show as i got it working by this! If you need complete patched module , you can ask me :)

Comment: tried everything but not working.... :-(