# My Toshiba Touchpad not working

Tags: 12.04, touchpad

Can you give a solution for this problem. My touch pad stopped working all of a sudden in 12.04. I think its a bug. Please give a solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you don'h have **donf-editor** install it:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

open **dconf-editor**

Then go to  **setting**-->**org**-->**gnome**-->**settings-daemon**-->**peripherals**-->**touchpad**

and set **touchpad-enabled** to true

[image]

Check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad) for more information about dealing with touchpad

Comment: But its not showing these settings.After installing this , it shows empty screen. please see this  https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-ykSfcUaMksI/UHkuJj8qtlI/AAAAAAAAAbc/qRNQbriAQlQ/s800/Screenshot%2520from%25202012-10-13%252014%253A28%253A39.png

Comment: you have to expand the tree list click on the left small arrow beside the app tab then move as indicated above in the answer

Comment: Still my touch pad is not working, how can i fix this bug , what i have to install ??

Comment: It's already enabled there. but not showing in xinput -list