# Toshiba Satellite P745 Touchpad problem

Tags: touchpad, toshiba

Good day to all,

I am using a Toshiba Satellite P745 installed with Ubuntu 14.04. I suddenly cannot use my laptop's touchpad to move my cursor, but if I am using a USB mouse, it is working perfectly. I followed this guide in order to check whether the touchpad is enabled using dconf-editor, but it is already enabled.

```
 if dconf-editor is not installed,

     sudo apt-get install dconf-tools

     then go to setting-->org-->gnome-->settings-daemon-->peripherals-->touchpad

     and set touchpad-enabled to true
```

I also tried to use the FN-F5 / FN-F9 functionality of Toshiba laptops, but it still did not work.

I also tried a suggestion made by help.ubuntu, in order to fix this problem regarding the touchpad, you must run this certain command via terminal (it is somehow similar to dconf-editor), and it did not work at all.

```
gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad/touchpad_enabled true
```

Lastly, I tried to verify whether my touchpad is recognized via terminal

```
xinput --list
```

it returned the id of my touchpad which is 13, and by doing

```
xinput --list-props 13
```

I was able to get further information regarding my touchpad, and with the results that I got, it clearly states that my touchpad is enabled

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
Device Enabled (141):   1
```

Based from this result, it means that my touchpad is enabled. Why is it then that my touchpad is not working?

I would greatly appreciate anyone who would be able to help me fix this problem.

Source for the dconf-editor installation:

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/199581/my-toshiba-touchpad-not-working
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also happen to my laptop after I've installed Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.2. 
The solution for my problem was (perhaps this would also work for you) to install the following package.

```
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Because this package is not automatically installed by default. I don't know why they don't do this by default. Hope it works for you as well.
Cheers.