# Ubuntu 14.04 Trackpad not working (left and right click work)

Tags: mouse, touchpad, trackpad

I was recently updating my Radeon graphics drivers, pre install the trackpad was functioning as normal, post install i can only left or right click.

Running xinput list returns that i have
      Virtual core pointer
        Virtual core XTEST pointer
        SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad

But when i run synclient it tells me
"Couldnt find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?"

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my problem is (perhaps this would also work for you) to install the following package.

```
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

See my answer in [Toshiba Satellite P745 Touchpad problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/595136/toshiba-satellite-p745-touchpad-problem/596116#596116)

Cheers