# My touchpad doesn't work on Dell N5110

Tags: dell, touchpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable multi touch on a Dell inspiron n5110 with an ALPS touchpad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104431/how-do-i-enable-multi-touch-on-a-dell-inspiron-n5110-with-an-alps-touchpad)

I have a dell inspiron 5110 laptop that has problem with touchpad in ubuntu(it's multitouch didn't work) . i follow this question's guilds and my touchpad doesn't work anymore. and now i use an external mouse.