# Mouse and trackpad stopped working on an Asus Eee1215n

Tags: mouse

I have an [Asus Eee 1215n](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=eee+pc+1215n&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=11431660390122533823&sa=X&ei=dk2rT6fbFMKsiQKrt5WsAg&ved=0CI0BEPMCMAE).

I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 and the USB mouse *and* trackpad just stopped working. What could've caused that? How do I go about debugging it?

Comment: I'd hit up your /var/log/Xorg.0.log first and look for errors pertaining to your mouse.  See if there are any EE lines that give any clues.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following [link](https://askubuntu.com/q/127567/46524) too, which was also a similar issue with a hp mini netbook.

Answer (score -3):

do you use lightdm? give gdm a try

sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
and choose gdm as default.

I hope this helps anyone.